# TypeError: (0 , next_sanity__WEBPACK_IMPORTED_MODULE_0__.createImageUrlBuilder) is not a function

Tags: typescript, next.js, sanity

I am trying  to make nextjs typescript project using sanity.io but im not able to solve this problem. itis showing that createImageUrlBuilder is not a function.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HeAAD.png)

[here is my sanity module](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vHtS1.png)

Answer (score 16, accepted):

`createImageUrlBuilder` is no longer wrapped by `next-sanity` and you'll need to install the dependency yourself (https://github.com/sanity-io/next-sanity#createimageurlbuilder-is-removed)

```
$ npm install @sanity/image-url
// or
$ yarn add @sanity/image-url
```

Notice also that `createImageUrlBuilder` is now a **default import**.

```
-import { createImageUrlBuilder } from 'next-sanity'
+import createImageUrlBuilder from '@sanity/image-url'
```

Answer (score 8):

You need to pass the sanity client in createImageUrlBuilder instead of config.

```
import createClient from '@sanity/client';
import createImageUrlBuilder from '@sanity/image-url';


const config = sanityClient({
   projectId: process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_SANITY_PROJECT_ID, 
   
   ...
  });

export const  sanityClient = createClient(config);

export const urlFor = (source) => createImageUrlBuilder(client).image(source); // <-----------
```

Answer (score 4):

First run this command

```
npm install --save @sanity/image-url
```

Import createImageUrlBuilder

```
import createImageUrlBuilder from "@sanity/image-url";
```

It worked for me this way.

Answer (score 2):

First install @sanity/image-url

```
$ npm install @sanity/image-url 
//or 
$ yarn add @sanity/image-url
```

`import imageUrlBuilder from "@sanity/image-url";`

`export const urlFor = (source) => imageUrlBuilder(config).image(source);`

use **imageUrlBuilder** instead of **createImageUrlBuilder** . It worked for me , Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

When you want to import "urlFor" in your components, make sure you import like this...

```
import { urlFor } from "../lib/sanity";
```